# Why didn't the Task Force capture Misa Amane?

Tags: death-note

After the final meeting and Light's death, everyone in the room knew the truth. They knew that the 13 day rule was fake, and the rule about destroying the Death Note was fake, too.

They also had many evidences against Misa (the tapes, fingerprints, hair, etc.), and Light also screamed "Misa write their names".

At this point, they had enough proof that Misa was Second Kira, but why didn't they capture her? Why did they let her go?

Comment: This was never explained in the manga, so we will never know.

Comment: It's been years since I've read Death Note lol. Interesting question though... Is it possible that I can suspect Light of setting up Misa as a scapegoat?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I thought she committed suicide before they got to her?

Comment: @BCLC Well there was more than a year between their deaths, so I assume they must have let her off the hook, because they knew where she lived.

Comment: Actually, I guess they didn't arrest her because she was cleared when Soichiro fake shot Light. The second kira kind of just vanished after then. Come to think of it, kind of weird how no one was wondering what happened to the second kira

Comment: Well L didn't really forget. Upon obtaining the notebook from higuchi, he mentally note ' s that there is a second book still out there, then they kind of moved to questioning Rem and I don't think L really ever got to bring up searching for the 2nd note with everyone's focus on Light's and Misa' innocence

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to consider all the times she was held under watch for one reason or another. First was under suspicion for being the second kira, during which she lost her memories and the bulk of the task force then believed she was innocent and harmless (aside from L who was figuring out why she went from determinedly silent to the ditzy blonde) Then after L's death, Near manages to bring up Aizawa ' s doubts involving Light, and even misa. So with Ide and Mogi to back him up, they have Mogi keep an eye on her under the guise of police protection where she does nothing even hinting at ulterior motives (having already submitted ownership to Mikami per Light's order)

Finally you have Near and the SPK keeping her and Mogi in captivity under surveillance again until 1 hour before the meet up where Misa is dropped off at a high class hotel and allowed to call Light.
Near knew full well in his theorizing that Misa was the 2nd kira. But by this point it would stand to reason that they all deemed her no longer a threat. With the last 2 books burned and no sympathetic shinigami to give her a new one and restore her memories, she could really do nothing about the situation and doesn't even know she committed any crime.

Comment: But in the manga Mikami likely also forgot that he committed murderers.

Comment: That would be true if he had given up ownership of his death note. I'm not sure a crazed Mikami would have known or thought to give it up, assuming he knew he would lose his memories anyways. Instead his notebook had been stolen the day prior, which leaves it in his possession and he would still have possession of it for another 489 days according to the death note rule 2.2 concerning "situations surrounding ownership." On top of that, he actually is caught red handed in attempting to commit multiple murders by a total of 8 law enforcement agents involved in the case (assuming you count Near)

Comment: I also forgot, but this rule is sighted in Vol. 3 p 66 on rule page XII if you wanted an exact reference; "If you lose the death note or have it stolen, you will lose its ownership unless you retrieve it within 490 days."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the author don't want to lower the excitement in climax because even Near going after Mesa can't prove she is second kira which may leave us a puzzled climax. Mesa lost her memories after forsaking the ownership of her notebook. Near won't be able to prove she is second kira because N works almost like L it will be same like when L tried to prove Mesa as second kira by confining her and Lite for month. There is one secret that Near still unaware of, deathnote ownership and he obviously don't know if deathnote owner forsaken their ownership their memories are lost and when come in contact with their deathnote they can regain their memories until their contact with deathnote. Even if they captured Mesa for investigation they may never make her touch deathnote cause they know of second kira eye power danger. If after writing Lite name in his notebook Reyuk(shinigami) will take Lites deathnote and go to his world. Near and other police will be left with a deathnote without shinigami. Then also they can never know of deathnote ownership.

Answer (score -1):

all they had was misa's clothes fiber if I recall correctly...the better question is why would they ignore the false finger prints and put the weight on the clothes fiber...so L rightfully figured that the prints were false but the fibers thats where its at?

Also you can probably presume they did go after her...didnt the show end at that point

Comment: Remember the question is talking about the end of the series. L is long since dead. also this doesn't answer as to ***Why the task force didn't capture Misa after Light's death***

Answer (score -3):

She was let go because to be a GOD you have to have the brains to kill. Of course she was just killing for Light, also she almost did no harm, just what was right for her lover. And then again she's suffered enough halving her lifespan twice now, She might have not much long to live.

But why was she let free? If you remember she's lost memory of all that she did. The detectives must have thought she was innocent enough that they let her go.

EDIT: They skipped her because she was distancing away from the main character and the author was too focused on its main pieces like "L" simply being killed in the middle of the anime :D

Comment: I don't really buy this. Regardless of whether Misa was a Light-level danger (or even a Mikami-level danger), the Task Force still had evidence that she was responsible for several murders. It doesn't matter how dumb you are--people with mental disabilities still have to stand trial for murder. It doesn't matter (usually) how long you have to live--Nazi officers responsible for atrocities in the Holocaust have been hunted down in their 80s and 90s and made to stand trial for their actions.

Comment: Bringing real life to anime eh? There are different laws in anime, and Im not saying she has mental disabilities, she just does not think the same  way does not want to achieve the same goals , she has already achieved in her own way :) Im sure that if you where the detectives, you'd not even suspect her in the first place, she was suspected only because Light was their real suspect, they had nothing on her :)

Comment: Cough Cough , If you want to bring a little bit of reality :P If you take down a mafia boss then all the people that worked for him are suspicious only if they are wanted too :)

Comment: Sure, but the question states that the Task Force had evidence against Misa--thus she should have been wanted. The fact that Mac the Knife hangs out with Don Corneo, known mafia boss, isn't evidence that he's a criminal. Fingerprints on the gun used in a murder are. Light yelling "Misa, write down their names!" by itself wouldn't have been any kind of evidence, but Near had evidence which the original L had collected that strongly suggested Misa was the Second Kira and had killed several people--and yet he chose not to arrest her. You don't address that in your answer.

Comment: You are right here, but don't forget, she only did what she did because she was ordered, and they might just have given up on her, the anime was more about hunting "The Boss" rather than taking care of normal civilians or their friends, As Far as I remember even the president of USA gave people up to save his own life ;)