# What happened to the second kira?

Tags: death-note

After Light and Misa were cleared, everyone seemed to just forget about that there's more than one kira. What was up with that? I seem to recall Light instructed Misa to make a response to the task force's kira video, then L deduced that the two kiras have met, then Light and Misa were confined, then Soichiro fake shoots them and then they try to catch Higuchi. While trying to catch Higuchi and thereafter, has everyone just forgotten that there's more than one kira? Did anyone find it suspicious that there seems to have been only one kira around? Maybe they thought that the two kiras were acting as one?

Based on a comment I made here: [Why didn't the Task Force capture Misa Amane?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/23695/why-didnt-the-task-force-capture-misa-amane#comment37106_23695)

Comment: What makes you think that happened? In L's mind Ligh was still Kira and Misa was still Kira 2, he was making preparations for the 13-days rule to be tested and would have proven it wrong thus confirming Light and Misa as Kira and Kira 2. That's the exact reason why Rem killed him. The rest of the task force knew that Kira and Kira 2 met and probably got along. Why would the Kiras still act as 2 entities? The task force knows that there are 2 Kiras who teamed up (or that one killed or subdued the other) and tries to get at least one of them hoping that this would lead to the 2nd one.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing to expect from the Task Force. Their main brains were L, Light and Near.

L proposed that Misa is the second Kira, but he was proved wrong because of the fake shot scene by Light's father. So inside the Task Force's mind, the claim that Misa is the second Kira became false, thus the claim of second Kira was probably forgotten too by the Task Force.

After Higuchi's capture part, L still didn't forget his claim about the second Kira and Kira = Light, because L wanted to test the truth of 13-day rules. Unfortunately he didn't live long.

Task Force is just a group of subordinates who receive the orders and execute the orders. They are not the leader of the team. They just follow their leader's instruction. They didn't have insight like L and Near, plus they believes in Light, so they just did their job according to Light's instructions. Even though Aizawa doubted Light after Near emerges, he still didn't have enough brain to prove Light = Kira, and he just had doubt, not confirmation.

As part of a team, Japanese values teamwork and harmony in a team, so they follow their leader. As for the guy who doubted Light, he chose to follow Near's instruction.

Comment: Not convinced, but now that you mention Aizawa I'm guessing he was suspicious of Misa. Been awhile since I've seen DN though

Answer (score 2):

They did not forget that there were possibly two Kiras. The task force stopped pursuing that objective due to L throwing the theory out after the shot scene as posted about.

If L didn't pursue the theory, then it was forgotten as the task force had already been proven powerless to stop Kira, which is why L was there in the first place.

Perhaps the individual members still pondered if there were two Kiras or not, but they were not free to pursue their own opinions given their individual positions.

Comment: Edited question. Does your answer change?

Comment: No mine remains the same however also remember that Higuchi's murders were far different in path and purpose than classic kira and kira 2.0(i.e Misa). So since that was the evidence in front of them L didn't have much of a choice besides his gut feeling which is shown a bit in the anime.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I watched Death Note, but this is my answer from what I remember.

I don't think they forgot about the Second Kira, at least not entirely. After the fake firing scene, they concluded that Light and Misa are not the Kiras.

Later Light turned out to be Kira, but I don't think they never had any reason to suspect Misa again. Also, the task force got hold of one of the Death Notes. So, they probably might have thought that since they have one with them and Kira has another one, Second Kira didn't have a Death Note anymore and so is no longer a threat.

That's what I think.